# Possibles ways to define the Riemann integral

Tags: limits, reference-request, definite-integrals, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

Can you recommend some nice papers or texts that discuss in detail the different ways to define Riemann integrability (for bounded functions defined on a compact interval of the real line)?

For instance, the main approach in Spivak's book is via upper and lower sums; it is only in an appendix that he brings up Riemann sums. What would be an example of a serious book that develops the theory the other way round (Riemann sums first)?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral should suffice

Comment: I was expecting something more...

Comment: I don't have any text in mind, but what more do you want?  The article discusses both approaches in detail.

Comment: Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis is a pretty standard book on this topic. You're wasting your time if you read any other analysis text.

Comment: @Herb: Do the Wikipedians explain why it is that Spivak chose the upper and lower sums approach insted of the one via Riemann sums?

Comment: I believe that a Wikipedia article won't generally tell you the answer to a question like the previous one; I want to believe that users of the StackExchange network are in general more knowledgeable than Wikipedians.

Comment: "In educational settings, the Darboux integral offers a simpler definition that is easier to work with; it can be used to introduce the Riemann integral. The Darboux integral is defined whenever the Riemann integral is, and always gives the same result..." From the Wikipedia link